# Naming of lower_bound, upper_bound c++

Tags: stl

Does any one know why they where given these names? Comming from a maths backgound they always left my mind in tangles since they are both mathematical lower bounds i.e. minimums in the finite world. Also the natural language definition given in the stl is a bad mental model imo.

Does anyone use mental synonyms to be able to work with them, or do they just remember the naïve implementations?

```
lower_bound(rng, x) = get_iter_to(mathematical_lower_bound(rng | filter([](auto y)
                                  {return x<=y;}))
upper_bound(rng, x) = get_iter_to(mathematical_lower_bound(rng | filter([](auto y)
                                  {return x<y;})))
```

[image]

Comment: `lower_bound` returns the leftmost position in a sorted sequence where a given value can be inserted while preserving the order. `upper_bound` returns the rightmost such position. The two may be different when the sequence contains equivalent elements; or at least, one element equivalent to the value. Another way to think about it - they are two bounds around the (possibly empty) range of elements equivalent to a given value (see also: `equal_range`)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks I get it now. You could post that as an answer

Comment: Great answers. also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61193289/10027592) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41958581/10027592) questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example from `std::ranges::lower_bound` ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/lower_bound)) is more helpful

```cpp
std::vector data = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
 
    auto lower = ranges::lower_bound(data, 4);
    auto upper = ranges::upper_bound(data, 4);
 
    ranges::copy(lower, upper, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
 
    std::cout << '\n'; // 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Igor Tandetnik answered this in the comments.

The set in question is the the elements which the given value can be inserted before while preserving the order.

For example if we want to insert `2` in to the range `[0,1,2,2,3,4]` then we could insert it at index 2, 3 or 4. `lower_bound` gives the iterator to the start of the range. `upper_bound` gives the last element in this range.

I suppose this is a name for library implementers writing pivots, rather than me trying to look up keys/indices of a vector of numerics.